# How do I create drag in P5.js and angular

Tags: angular, p5.js

I am trying to create a function to drag or move the shape after being placed on the canvas but it is not changing the shape but the rectX and rectY did change. The image is stationed and not working.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import * as p5 from 'p5';
import { DrawingService } from '../services/drawing-service.services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drawing-canvas',
  templateUrl: './drawing-canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drawing-canvas.component.scss']
})

export class DrawingCanvasComponent implements OnInit {
 
  private p5: any;
  public canvas: any;
  public points: any[] = [];
  public sw = 2;
  public c: any[] = [];
  public strokeColor = 0;
  public currentTool!: string;
  public currentColor!: string;
  public currentThickness!: number;
  public currentSize!: number;
  public isDraggable: boolean = false;
  public rectX: number = 100;
  public rectY: number = 300;
  public dragPoint: any;
  public shapes: any[] = [];
  public isRectSelected: boolean = false;

  constructor(private drawingService: DrawingService) {
    this.drawingService.toolChanged.subscribe(tool => {
      this.currentTool = tool;
    });

    this.drawingService.colorChanged.subscribe(color => {
      this.currentColor = color;
    });

    this.drawingService.thicknessChanged.subscribe(thickness => {
      this.currentThickness = thickness;
    });

    this.drawingService.sizeChanged.subscribe(size => {
      this.currentSize = size;
    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const sketch = (s: any) => {
      s.setup = () => {
        s.createCanvas(s.windowWidth - 200, s.windowHeight - 200).parent('sketch-holder');
        s.background(255);
        s.strokeWeight(this.sw);

  
       this.c[0] = s.color(255, 0, 0); // red

        //s.rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);

        s.stroke(this.c[this.strokeColor]);
      };

      s.draw = () => {
        if (this.currentTool === 'Pen'){
            if (s.mouseIsPressed) {
                if (s.mouseButton === s.LEFT) {
                    s.line(s.mouseX, s.mouseY, s.pmouseX, s.pmouseY);
                  } else if (s.mouseButton === s.CENTER) {
                    s.background(255);
                  }
            }  
        }

      
        if(this.currentTool === 'Rectangle') {
          // draw a rectangle on the canvas
         
          if (s.mouseIsPressed) {
            if (s.mouseButton === s.LEFT) { 
              s.drawRectangle(this.rectX, this.rectY, 200, 100);
            }else if (s.mouseButton === s.CENTER) {
              s.background(255);
            }
          
          }
        
        }

        if(this.currentTool === 'Hand') {
         
          console.log(this.currentTool)
          s.mouseClicked = () => {
            // Check if the mouse is inside the rectangle
            console.log(s.mouseX > this.rectX && s.mouseX < this.rectX + 200 && s.mouseY > this.rectY && s.mouseY < this.rectY + 100)
          // if (s.mouseX !== null && s.mouseY !== null && s.mouseX !== this.rectX && s.mouseY !== this.rectY) 
           
            {
              // Start dragging the rectangle
              this.isRectSelected = true;
              this.dragPoint = { x: s.mouseX, y: s.mouseY };
             
            }
          
          };
          
         // Update the rectangle's position if the mouse has moved while it is being dragged
          s.mouseMoved = () => {
            if (this.isRectSelected && s.mouseX > 0 && s.mouseX < s.width && s.mouseY > 0 && s.mouseY < s.height) {
  
              if (s.mouseX !== this.dragPoint.x || s.mouseY !== this.dragPoint.y) {
                
                this.rectX += s.mouseX - this.dragPoint.x;
                this.rectY += s.mouseY - this.dragPoint.y;
                this.dragPoint = { x: s.mouseX, y: s.mouseY };
              }
            }
          };
          
          s.mouseReleased = () => {
            // Stop dragging the rectangle
            this.isRectSelected = false;
          };
          
  
        }

      };

  
      s.drawRectangle = (x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number) => {
       return this.shapes.push(s.rect(x, y, w, h));
      
      }

 
      s.keyPressed = () => {
        if (s.key === 'c') {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      };
  
    };

    this.canvas = new p5(sketch);
  }

}
```

I tried it with s.mouseX and s.mouseX and place it in the draw() but it was messy, displaying the paths around.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not clearing your screen while using hand tool .

try this

```
this.rectX += s.mouseX - this.dragPoint.x;
this.rectY += s.mouseY - this.dragPoint.y;
this.dragPoint = { x: s.mouseX, y: s.mouseY };
s.background(255);
```